# Can't add y=log(y) in vertical axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
group, x,  y 
1.10,  0.1,0.1
1.10,  2,  2.2
1.10,  3,  2.1
1.10,  4,  1.5
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\begin{axis}
\addplot table [discard if not={group}{1.10}, x=x, ymode=log, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not checked, but you have a 0 in the y values, and you can't take the logarithm of 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
group, x,  y 
1.10,  0.1, 0
1.10,  2,  2.2
1.10,  3,  2.1
1.10,  4,  1.5
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymode=log, ymin=1, ymax=10]
\addplot table[x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Semilog plot with three points]

Comment: but now i can,t separate between groups of datas.

Comment: Your `discard if not` style is unrelated to this question. You can add it back, if you want.

Comment: is there any way to add the scaling in all four sides?

Comment: Yes. I do not think there is an option for that, so it involves adding the same axis again without drawing it, but with tick labels on the other side. You need to ask a new question about that.